# UnicodeEncodeError when writing Pandas DataFrame into sqlite3 Database

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, character-encoding

I basically want to save a CSV-file into a database. The simplified version of my code looks somehow like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', encoding='latin-1')

con = sqlite.connect('path/to/db')
cur = con.cursor()
```

And when I'm calling

```
df.to_sql('foo', con, if_exists='replace')
```

I am geeting the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there a way to tell Python to encode the file to something different than ascii? Or how do I decode file.csv properly when opening it?

Comment: You need to use the real encoding of file.csv in the parameter 'encoding=' (instead of 'latin-1')

Comment: Actually it was `utf-8-sig`. The encoding was changed when I made some changes in the file with Sublime Text.

Comment: So use UTF8 when read the file :)